# TypeError: Music.on_wavelink_track_end() got multiple values for argument 'track'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

I making discord music bot and use wavelink library.

I write this code:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_wavelink_track_end(player: wavelink.Player, track: wavelink.Track):
        ctx = player.ctx
        vc: player = ctx.voice_client

        if vc.loop:
            return await vc.play(track)
        
        next_song = vc.queue.get()
        await vc.play(next_song)
        await ctx.send(f"Сейчас играет {next_song.title}")


    @commands.command()
    async def play(self,ctx: commands.Context, *, search: wavelink.YouTubeTrack):
        if not ctx.author.voice:
            return await ctx.send("Ты не в голосовом канале!", delete_after = 10)
        if not ctx.voice_client:
            vc: wavelink.Player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls = wavelink.Player) 
        else:
            vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
        
        if vc.queue.is_empty and vc.is_playing:
            await vc.play(search)
            m = search.duration/60
            await ctx.send(f"Сейчас играет `{search.title}` продолжительностью `{round(m, 2)}` минут")
        else:
            await vc.queue.put_wait(search)
            await ctx.send(f"Добавлен {search.title} трек в очередь")
        vc.ctx = ctx
        setattr(vc, "loop", False)
```

And also I got this error

```
TypeError: Music.on_wavelink_track_end() got multiple values for argument 'track'
```

Another commands works properly, but play command do not append to wavelink queue and just play new song if we type `play` again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_wavelink_track_end(player: wavelink.Player, track: wavelink.Track):

#You need to pass in `self` to here   ⤴
```

So your code will look like this

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_wavelink_track_end(self, player: wavelink.Player, track: wavelink.Track):
        ctx = player.ctx
        vc: player = ctx.voice_client

        if vc.loop:
            return await vc.play(track)
        
        next_song = vc.queue.get()
        await vc.play(next_song)
        await ctx.send(f"Сейчас играет {next_song.title}")


    @commands.command()
    async def play(self,ctx: commands.Context, *, search: wavelink.YouTubeTrack):
        if not ctx.author.voice:
            return await ctx.send("Ты не в голосовом канале!", delete_after = 10)
        if not ctx.voice_client:
            vc: wavelink.Player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls = wavelink.Player) 
        else:
            vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
        
        if vc.queue.is_empty and vc.is_playing:
            await vc.play(search)
            m = search.duration/60
            await ctx.send(f"Сейчас играет `{search.title}` продолжительностью `{round(m, 2)}` минут")
        else:
            await vc.queue.put_wait(search)
            await ctx.send(f"Добавлен {search.title} трек в очередь")
        vc.ctx = ctx
        setattr(vc, "loop", False)
```

> This is probably it.

• Sxviaat

Answer (score 0):

simply add self
async def on_wavelink_track_end(self , player: wavelink.Player, track: wavelink.Track)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).